# How to reference another cell as a wildcard from a separate worksheet, within the same workbook, when using SUMIF function?

Tags: database, excel, wildcard, worksheet-function, sumifs

I am trying to use the contents of a cell from a different worksheet as part of the wildcard criteria within my SUMIF function elsewhere. Here is what I have that is returning the correct value:

```
=SUMIF('PASTE SAP DATA HERE'!H:H,'PASTE SAP DATA HERE'!L:L,D23&"*")
```

I would like to use the same value within D23 but from a separate worksheet where it should be stored:

```
=SUMIF('PASTE SAP DATA HERE'!H:H,'PASTE SAP DATA HERE'!L:L,'March SAP Core Data'!A18&"*")
```

The second attempt currently returns the value 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at the data, make sure there are no spaces or other non visible characters that might be throwing off the matches.  If the matches are numbers or dates, make sure that both are true numbers or dates and not text that look like numbers or dates.  The formula looks like it should work.

Comment: Wow, such an obvious mistake that I completely ignored. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

"Look at the data, make sure there are no spaces or other non visible characters that might be throwing off the matches. If the matches are numbers or dates, make sure that both are true numbers or dates and not text that look like numbers or dates. The formula looks like it should work. – Scott Craner"

-From comments